# How to use BoxFit.values in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Flutter has a `BoxFit` function called `BoxFit.values` which we can use inside `fit:` as a property of `Image.network()`.
Let's say my code is like this:

```
Image.network(
  '${myImageUrl}',
  fit: BoxFit.values,
)
```

Then can `BoxFit.values` be included in several `BoxFit` parameters at the same time as `BoxFit.contain` and `BoxFit.scaleDown`?
If yes, how to use it?

I've searched for information [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit.html#:%7E:text=inherited-,Constants,-values%20%E2%86%92%20const%20List), but do not understand how to use it.

Thank You

Comment: `BoxFit.values` is a list with all enum values, not another enum value you can use

Comment: Can you answer with an example, so i it can be easier to understand?

Comment: example: `print(BoxFit.contain); print(BoxFit.values);`

Comment: Ohhh, so its just a function to know which enum values that the Widget use?

Comment: It's not a function, it's a list with all possible enum values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BoxFit.values` is just the default list of enum values that contains all enum values. All enum has the `values` property.

If you want to use `.values` you could use an index like this:

```
Image.network(
  '${myImageUrl}',
  fit: BoxFit.values[0], //same as BoxFit.fill
)
```

But it's not intended for use. Use the respective enum constants instead.